# OneDrive and Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, home-directory

I can't find information about this anymore so I am guessing this is highly unlikely scenario and probably not possible. However I wondered if someone has ever attempted it.
Has anyone tried using OneDrive as your home dir for users in Ubuntu ? I have machines running Ubuntu 20 and 18 (moving to 20). All users on laptops use local directory while networked PCs use network home. I was wondering about possibility of moving everyone to onedrive which would be the same we do for windows.

Comment: It might be safer to keep the users' home directories local, but instead of having Documents, Pictuires, Music etc directories within their home, remove thiose directories and replace them with symlinks to equivalent directories in their one drive account. I have done this not with symlinks to onedrive, but to another mounted disk, and it works fine. But onedrive will have to be mounted as a normal mount point in order to symlink to it, I don't know if that is the case as I'm not very familiar with onedrive. (`ln -s` is the command you need in case you are unfamiliar.)

Comment: If you want to mount your /home/<username> from an external server (that is not having it on your local disk) you could take  look at the `autofs` package. This will handle mounting of an external filesystem when it is accessed, and unmount it again after some specified time.

Answer (score 0):

> All users on laptops use local directory while networked PCs use network home. I was wondering about possibility of moving everyone to onedrive which would be the same we do for windows.

As the developer|maintainer of the free Linux OneDrive Client (https://abraunegg.github.io/), this would be entirely possible with careful client configration.

Each user would have to have their own specific configuration & OneDrive account, and you would have to take care to configure the client not to upload|sync specific directories to ensure that the security of that user is not impacted - eg, not uploading `.config` & `.pki` user directories.

Comment: Each users credentials are the same for office 365 and login to our systems. I suppose this would make life easier. However what Im wondering about would it be possible to get one drive to mount at the point of login so that we do not have to store passwords on the machine ? So for example to mount shared drives I use pam module to mount them on login by grabbing users credentials and searching which groups that person is part off would something similar be possible ?

Comment: RE: "Each users credentials are the same for office 365 and login to our systems."

That is a quite a major security hole for your data if true.

Comment: RE: "However what Im wondering about would it be possible to ..."

No this is not possible. You have to use the OneDrive Login Authentication URL, log in with the Office365 users credentials, then obtain the token from the URI, pass that back to the application to have the application be successfully authenticated.

Comment: Sorry but how is it a major security hole ? (I failed to mention Azure AD)

Comment: "Each users credentials are the same" -

If the credentials are the 'same' that is a security hole

Comment: Well, we have our own tenancy its basically same account its not 2 different accounts but this is now going off topic it would be whole other discussion.